# Best practice to append a struct type to another

Tags: c++

I'm designing some data structures which are used as transformed packages like these:

```
struct Header {
  int header_member;
};

struct Tail {
  int tail_member;
  char data[];  //flexible array here, or char data[0], or char *data... the point
                //is that the data holds an continual memory, that's why it must be at last
};

struct BodyA : public Header{
  int ba;
  Tail tail;
};

struct BodyB : public Header{
  int bb;
  Tail tail;
};
```

It's a little uncomfortable when accessing the members in `Tail`:

```
int main() {
  BodyA a;
  a.header_member = 1;
  a.tail.tail_member = 2;
}
```

As you can see, unlike access header_meber directly, I have to use `tail.tail_member` to access tail's member, this is not very intuitive, especially if this is a public API for users.

So any way I can "append" a tail struct to another, in order to call the tail's member directly?

Edit: Give the real problem I met to make this question clearer:

```
struct CompressedHeader {
  unsigned int original_size;
  unsigned int compressed_size;
  char compressed_data[];
};

struct TextFile {
  int lines;
  CompressedHeader compressed_header;
};


struct ImageFile {
  int width, height, channels;
  CompressedHeader compressed_header;
};


int main() {
  ImageFile* imageFile = (ImageFile*) new char[sizeof(ImageFile) + 32 /* 32 bytes for compressed data */];
}
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance is an option as well, although this will make memory layout different (if that matters).

Comment: You need to read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), and learn about `virtual` methods and [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) used to implement them. See also   [this C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/)

Comment: There's nothing called "header_member' or "tail_member" declared anywhere, as such the shown code example does not even compile, or make much sense.

Comment: you could expose getters to hide the internal structure. Also notice that substructures might introduce padding (this question looks like memory layout is of importance for you)

Comment: Also this question is "how to improve my solution" instead "how to solve particular problem".

Comment: You would not normally provide users with access to data members as then you have no way of maintaining any kind of integrity of your data. If you design an API then you have the flexibility to layout the data as you wish.

Comment: Tail's `char* data[];` is not C++.

Comment: I changed the code once but it seems that it didn't uploaded successfully

Comment: Why do they have to be in this order? Normally you would do `struct BodyA : Header, Tail {...}` (note that `public` is unnecessary here since it's the default for structs)

Comment: @user253751 because there's an flexible array member (`char data[]`) in `Tail`, it must be the last member of a struct, that how this question comes from

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't support flexible array members

Comment: @UnholySheep or `char data[0]` or even just "char * data", the point here is that the data holds an continual memory, that's why it must be at last.